# storing an attribute in a variable as a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, attributes

I am trying to use the name of an atrribute and place it in a selector but it is not working.
I have done it with ID's before many times.

```
var x = $('input:checked').attr('value');//this should return the value.
```

then i have a div with the same name:

```
$('.' + x).show();
```

when x is alone it shows it as a string when I use the firebug console, but when I use it with show() nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works just fine, but please validate the following:

1. The `input` is actually `checked`;
2. There exists an element whose **`class`** is the `value` of the `checked` checkbox.

Here's a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HwyFZ/)** of your code.

> then i have a div with the same name:

Do you mean a div with the attribute `name` equal to the `checkbox` value? If it is, you need to use `$('[name="' + x + '"]').show()` instead. The dot selector is for *classes*.

Comment: my value had capital letters so apparently that was a problem...it didnt match the class!

Comment: @shamguy4: Thought it'd be something like that : )